# Python reducing code with list comprehension

Tags: python

This code is for returning the cells with coordinates around the specific (takes in as a tuple) cell from a chart. Apparently using list comprehension I can reduce the number of code lines significantly. How would I go about using the list comprehension?

```
def get_neighbours(cell, size):
    x = cell[0]
    y = cell[1]
    neighbours = []

    if x - 1 >= 0 and x - 1 <= size - 1:
        neighbours += [(x - 1, y)]
    if x + 1 >= 0 and x + 1 <= size - 1:
        neighbours += [(x + 1, y)]
    if y - 1 >= 0 and y - 1 <= size - 1:
        neighbours += [(x, y - 1)]
    if y + 1 >= 0 and y + 1 <= size - 1:
        neighbours += [(x, y + 1)]

    return sorted(neighbours)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: What is wrong with the way you have it written now? "Reducing code lines" is not really a measure of quality. If you were to put this in a list comprehension (especially if you don't refactor is further), the list comprehension will be a long unreadable line of code. You read code more often than you write it, so think carefully before "compacting" code _especially if its already working_.

Comment: This is an example of code that shouldn't be in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

You've got some repeated code (bounds checking, and list appends), which suggests that a loop may be a good way to improve the code.

Here's how I'd write it:

```
def get_neighbours(cell, size):
    x, y = cell
    steps = (-1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1), (1, 0)
    return [(x+dx, y+dy) for dx, dy in steps
            if 0 <= x+dx < size and 0 <= y+dy < size]
```

While it's often better to use a for-loop and simple code rather than a list comprehension, I think this code works well and cleanly like this, and expresses the idea "for each direction, add the neighbouring cell if its in range" in a readable way.

Comment: Very elegant! But note that your codes doesn't perform the same (probably an error in the OP's code). For example, if `x > size + 2`, you'll give out no neighbors, while the OP's code will give out neighbors on the y-axis.